# Histogram of dates with a specific attribute

Tags: r, statistics

I have some data:

```
> (dput(head(data$Date,10)))
c("18.12.2003", "06.04.2005", "06.04.2005", "07.04.2005", "27.05.2005", 
"16.06.2009", "16.06.2009", "21.12.2009", "22.12.2009", "09.06.2011"
)
 [1] "18.12.2003" "06.04.2005" "06.04.2005" "07.04.2005" "27.05.2005"
 [6] "16.06.2009" "16.06.2009" "21.12.2009" "22.12.2009" "09.06.2011"
> (dput(head(data$Art,10)))
c("V", "K", "K", "K", "Zuteilung", "V", "K", "K", "K", "V")
 [1] "V"         "K"         "K"         "K"         "Zuteilung" "V"        
 [7] "K"         "K"         "K"         "V"
```

As you can see to every date there is a string value.

I can measure all the string values of `K` with:

```
> (length(grep("K", data$Art)))
```

I want to plot all frequencies of K with the same date.

With this I can plot all date, however this does not include the `K` Strings.

```
hist(as.Art(data$Date, '%d.%m.%Y'), breaks="days", freq=TRUE)
```

I really appreciate your answers!